# android horizontal scrollview

Tags: android

Hi
 am testing horizontal scrollview i came to a strange problem ,i put one button in horizontal scrollview with layout height and width fill_parent but that tag have no effect in layout ,lets look in to my layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        >
        <Button             
            android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

How can i fill the layout with my button inside horizontal scrollview

Comment: Set android:width="fill_parent" in horizontal scroll view........

Comment: @N-JOY, have you tried it? If yes, put it as an answer..

Comment: @N-JOY i put the <HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>  now i can see the button but it wont fill the entire layout

Answer (score 6):

the problem might be in `android:width="wrap_content"`....
as u did wrap content for horizontal scrollview and it is parent of linearlayout and button in above case.......
that might be creating all the problem...
either hard code size of linear layout or put `android:width="fill_parent"` in horizontal scroll view.....

Answer (score 0):

Remember that scroll view **layout_height** must be **warp_content** , **fill_parent** attribute does not affect on the scrollview height, if you want to fill whole screen by button   in your layout you should mentioned the **layout_height** hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

Put this two tag in HorizontalScrollView

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Put orientation in LinearLayout

android:orientation="vertical"

Do android:layout_height="fill_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" in HorizontalScrollView