# scroll is not appearing with ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

See the following code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />
           <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button06"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button07"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button08"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button09"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Using this I am not able to see Scroll in ScrollView.

Comment: Could it be so that it's vertical scrolling you're trying to achieve? If that's the case change LinearLayout orientation accordingly.

Comment: its horizontal scrolling i want to get

Comment: From ScrollView documentation; "ScrollView only supports vertical scrolling".

Comment: I think I need to use HorizontalScrollView
 This to this [Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988863/android-horizontal-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Horizontal ScrollView like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

//Everything goes here

</HorizontalScrollView>
```